# ActiveRecord::Migrationを継承したクラスでcreate_tableが呼べる仕組みを教えてください

Tags: rails-activerecord

Ruby on Railsの`ActiveRecord::Migration`クラスを継承したクラスでは`create_table`メソッドを呼ぶことができます。

この`create_table`メソッドの本体は`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements`にある`create_table`メソッドのようだ、ということはソースを読んで予想できました。

しかし、`Migration`クラスで`SchemaStatements`モジュールをincludeしているようでもないのに、なぜ`create_table`メソッドが呼べるのか、という仕組みがわかりません。

なぜ呼べるのか教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

簡単に答えが見つかるかと思いましたが、意外と難しいですね。

調べてみたところ、こちらのブログにほぼ答えが載っていました。

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/elm200/20061001/1159806806

簡単に言うと、 `ActiveRecord#method_missing` にて `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter` へ処理を委譲しているから`create_table`が呼べる、ということになります。

ただし、情報がちょっと古いのでRails 4.2.0のコードで確認してみました。

`method_missing`が処理を委譲しているコードはこちらになります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、 `connection` の中身である `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter` クラスはちゃんと `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements` をincludeしているようです。（もちろん、 `SQLite3Adapter` 以外の場合も同様です）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これでスッキリ解決！！かな？  
いかがでしょうか？

Comment: `create_table`メソッドが呼ばれるまでの経路が理解出来、スッキリしました。

ありがとうございます。